# JNI getObjectClass crashes VM

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a thing where C++ does logging to the java side via JNI.

So far I have a native setter:

```
public native void setLogger(Logger logger);
```

which I implement in C++:

```
void __stdcall Java_setLogger(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jobject loggerInstance)
{
    logger = Logger(env, &loggerInstance);
}
```

The constructor of the Logger class is as follows:

```
Logger::Logger(JNIEnv* env, jobject* loggerInstance)
{
    this->env = env;
    this->loggerInstance = *loggerInstance;
}
```

When I try to call a java method via JNI on the provided logger instance (from Java) it crashes the VM. I am not sure why because this is pieced together from other stackoverflow questions.

```
void Logger::debug(const std::string code, const std::string message) const
{
    std::cout << "debug!" << std::endl; //for debugging purposes

    jclass loggerClass = env->GetObjectClass(loggerInstance);
    std::cout << "class retrieved" << std::endl; //for debugging purposes

    if (loggerClass == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "logger class null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    jmethodID debugMethod = env->GetMethodID(loggerClass, "debug", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    std::cout << "method retrieved" << std::endl; //for debugging purposes

    if (debugMethod == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "debug method null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    env->CallVoidMethod(loggerInstance, debugMethod, code, message);
}
```

The console output:

```
debug!
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000067dbef23, pid=6812, tid=0x0000000000003354
```

The debug method on the Java side's logger is:

```
public final void debug(String code, String message) {
    ...
}
```

Finally, the error log file produced mentions:

```
Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.041 Thread 0x0000000000d9e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x0000000780987ca8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\
Event: 0.041 Thread 0x0000000000d9e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x0000000780987f90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims
```

Perhaps I should mention that the Java side is technically not Java; but it is Kotlin.

---

**UPDATE (SOLVED):**

So, I did as the answer below said but then I noticed I didn't even get to the "debug!" cout. I was very confused but then I realized that in my destructor, I always call `env->deleteGlobalRef(..)` and that I have a necessary default constructor (that initializes nothing) to be able to declare `Logger logger;` and initialize it later in C++.

Simply adding `if(loggerInstance != NULL)` before deleting the global ref solved everything. This is because C++ (visual c++) calls the destructor when I assign a new value, and it actually assigns a new instance when putting `Logger logger;` somewhere (from my observations anyways).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The garbage collector can move around objects on the Java side, so if you save your logger object like that: `this->loggerInstance = *loggerInstance`, it might be moved in between JNI calls, so when you try to use it in `GetObjectClass` the pointer might be dangling.

A safe way to store a pointer to a Java object is to use [`NewGlobalRef`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewGlobalRef) which creates a *pin* on the object:

```
this->loggerInstance = env->NewGlobalRef(*loggerInstance);
```

Just make sure to delete it again with `DeleteGlobalRef` when you're done using it (So apply rule of 5).

---

I will also point out that your last call: `env->CallVoidMethod(loggerInstance, debugMethod, code, message);` will not work. There is no automagical marshalling from an `std::string` to a `java.lang.String`. You could call [`NewStringUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) to create a Java String, and pass that.

Comment: Ah thanks, the reference kind of works like new in C++, only that you have to make Java aware of it then? Also thanks for the string part, I had high hopes but I already expected that. I had a couple of issues after this; I will update my question with it!

Comment: One last thing, do you recommend I always follow this approach with registering the globalref if I want to hold stuff from Java in C++?

Comment: @Limnic Yes, your C++ `Logger` class is basically managing a resource. So follow [RAII](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use jstring not a c++ string itself

```
void Logger::debug(const std::string code, const std::string message) const
{
    std::cout << "debug!" << std::endl; //for debugging purposes

    jclass loggerClass = env->GetObjectClass(loggerInstance);
    std::cout << "class retrieved" << std::endl; //for debugging purposes

    if (loggerClass == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "logger class null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }


    jstring javMessage = env->NewStringUTF((const char* )message.c_str());
    jstring javCode = env->NewStringUTF((const char* )code.c_str());

    jmethodID debugMethod = env->GetMethodID(loggerClass, "debug", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    std::cout << "method retrieved" << std::endl; //for debugging purposes

    if (debugMethod == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "debug method null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    env->CallVoidMethod(loggerInstance, debugMethod, javCode, javMessage);
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, but that was not the main problem. Thanks!